# How to call a shell script from Python in Windows Powershell?

Tags: python, bash, sh

I using a Python script to call a .sh script, as shown below

```
ret = subprocess.call('sh ./myScript.sh '+file_a+' '+file_b+' '+str(self.counter), shell=True)
```

The first two lines of myScript.sh are

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "sh script opened"
```

I can run myScript.sh directly from Windows Powershell, but not from my Python script(run in Powershell).  So, I know that myScript.sh is correct; however, I do not get output when run from my Python script  On a different computer, this call worked fine, but now it doesn't.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your `COMSPEC` environment variable? If it's cmd (or unset) rather than powershell, Python will run the command in a cmd subshell, which would explain why it doesn't give the same results as running the same command in powershell.

Answer (score 1):

As @abarnet mentioned in his comment there is a `COMSPEC` environement variable that you can change to point at `powershell` rather than `cmd`:

```
import os
import subprocess

print os.environ["COMSPEC"]
os.environ["COMSPEC"] = r"C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
print os.environ["COMSPEC"]
ret = subprocess.call('sh ./script.sh', shell=True)
print ret
```

Which on my Windows machine returns:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 
The term 'sh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included , verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:3
+ sh <<<<  ./script.sh
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```